# Kendo UI Grid - Additional Data - Json Array - MVC Model Binder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Using the Client Data Processing during Ajax Binding found in [Kendo Docs](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-binding#enable-client-data-processing-during-ajax-binding), I'm finding it very difficult to map the Json Array to the MVC ModelBinder.

```
@(Html.Kendo()
    .Grid<PickerDocumentViewModel>()
    .Name("DocumentAttachments")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read
            .Action("PickerDocuments", "DocumentRepository")
            .Data("GetSelectedDocuments")))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        ...
    }))
```

The JavaScript function GetSelectedDocuments returns a Json array of PickerDocumentViewModel. Using FireBug, I see the Post data looks most unusual:

```
0[Description]  Doug
0[EditedDateTime]   Fri Sep 13 2013 15:06:44 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)
0[FileExtension]    txt
1[Description]  a
1[EditedDateTime]   Mon Sep 09 2013 18:21:56 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)
1[FileExtension]    docx
```

As opposed to how MVC expects lists of objects to come in:

```
[0].Description Doug
```

So, how might I either 
1. Change the way Kendo forms the post data to play with standard MVC List ModelBinding?

```
    public ActionResult PickerDocuments([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, IList<PickerDocumentViewModel> viewModels)
    {
```

1. Or teach MVC how to ModelBind the way Kendo is sending it?

Comment: I posted an answer in the other support thread. Check the code library and use the approach from there.

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853779/mvc-how-to-modelbind-a-list-an-objects-with-this-unusual-post-data-format