# MVC - How to ModelBind a list an objects with this unusual post data format?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Normally when you ModelBind a list of objects with MVC, the action looks like so:

```
    public ActionResult Hello(List<DocumentViewModel> viewModels)
    {
```

And the Post data looks something like:

```
[0].Id 1
[0].Name Bob
[1].Id 2
[1].Name Jane
```

But, how could I get the following post data to work?

```
0[Id] 1
0[Name] Bob
1[Id] 2
1[Name] Jane
```

The Post data is being provided by Kendo UI, so I don't imagine I have much flexibility to change it.

**Update** Thanks Petur for the answer. To expand on his answer, this function:

```
common.MvcSerializeArray = function (array, prefix) {
    var result = {};

    if (!prefix) {
        prefix = '';
    }

    if (array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if ($.isPlainObject(array[i])) {
                for (var property in array[i]) {
                    result[prefix + "[" + i + "]." + property] = array[i][property];
                }
            } else {
                result[prefix + "[" + i + "]"] = array[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
};
```

should wrap arrays before being returned to Kendo's Data method:

```
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read
            .Action("PickerDocuments", "DocumentRepository")
            .Data(@<text>function(e) { return MyApp.Common.MvcSerializeArray(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))); }</text>)))
```

And voila, I get post data MVC ModelBinds with ease:

```
[0].Id 1
[0].Name Bob
[1].Id 2
[1].Name Jane
```

Comment: https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change it but you can add the desired format by sending addiotional parameters like explained [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-send-values-to-my-action-method-when-binding-the-grid?) for the Ajax Grid. Same approach is used in [this](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/using-multiselect-in-grid.aspx) code library (you can get the magic function inside of the code, it is used to send the multi-select values)

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thanks @Petur, the key was in that project. serializeArray doctored it right up!.

Comment: If possible share the magic function here for the rest of the community.